# Get Json info in laravel blade

Tags: json, laravel

I have json column in my table where data of it is like:

```
   {  
   "9997d217f153577526c5c51e2fb7b35a":{  
      "rowId":"9997d217f153577526c5c51e2fb7b35a",
      "id":1,
      "name":"grjyj",
      "qty":"1",
      "price":10,
      "options":{  
         "installation":true
      },
      "tax":0,
      "subtotal":10
   }
}
```

I Can have all the data by looping this column except `options` part where is array in array.

## Code

`my blade`

```
@foreach($invoice['content'] as $product)
  <tr>
    <td>
      {{$product['name']}}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{$product['qty']}}
    </td>
    <td>
    @foreach($product['options'] as $option)
      {{$option['installation']}}
    @endforeach
    </td>
    <td>
      ${{number_format($product['subtotal'], 0)}}
    </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

`screenshot`

[image: screenone]

### Question

1. How to get my `options` value?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## SOLVED

I have changed my loop to code below and it returns my values:

```
@foreach($product['options'] as $option => $result)
  {{ $result }}
@endforeach
```